# Prove: Completion of a normed space is a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Me again with another (most likely) easy problem that is too hard for me as of now.

> Suppose we have a normed space $(X,||\cdot||)$ and a map $i:X\rightarrow \hat X$ with $\overline{i(X)} = \hat X~$ (i.e. $\hat X$ is the completion of $X$).
>
> Prove that $\hat X$ is a Banach space w.r.t. the norm $||i(x)||_{\hat X}:=||x||_X~, \forall~ x \in X$.

Now, if my train of thought didn't derail too much, $||\cdot||_{|i(X)}$ already is a norm by definition.

But what about $\hat X \backslash i(X)$? Is there a canonical way to get that norm?

As long as I'm not totally desperate: Just hints please!

Thanks

**EDIT**:

I guess I'm still wrong somewhere, but could it work like that:

> Let {$x_n$}$_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$.
> $~\Rightarrow~$ {$i(x_n)$}$_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a CS in $\hat X$.
>
> Then $\exists ~x \in \hat X~$ s.t.  $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{i(x_n)}$ = x.
>
> We then define $||x||_{\hat X \backslash i(X)}:=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||i(x_n)||_{|i(X)} = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||x_n||_X$
>
> $\Leftrightarrow~ ||\cdot||_{\hat X \backslash i(X)} ~$ is a norm on $\hat X \backslash i(X)$,  since $\lim (a + b)= \lim a + \lim b$ and $||\cdot||_X$ is a norm

Is that a possible solution or is it totally stupid of me to even think that way?

**EDIT 2**:

Okay, if I do that, I get a seminorm. But that's not what I want and what I need. However, I don't see how $||i(x)||_{\hat X}$ correlates with $||\cdot||_{\text{~}}$ with {$x_n$} ~ {$y_n$} $\Leftrightarrow \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}||x_n - y_n|| = 0$, using the [Banach completion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BanachCompletion.html).

Comment: What do you mean by $\overline{i(X)}=\hat{X}$? Do you mean that $\hat{X}$ is the closure of the image of $X$ through $i$? If so what metric (or norm) on $\hat{X}$ are you using to define the closure?

Comment: @jkn: Um. "(i.e. $\hat X$ is the completion of $X$)." $i$ is an isometry $\Rightarrow d_{\hat X}(i(x),i(y))=||i(x-y)||_{\hat X} = ||x-y||_X = d_X (x,y)$

Comment: By definition, a completion of a metric space is complete, so what are you trying to show, that if $X$ is normed we can find a completion $\hat{X}$ that is also normed, whose norm satisfies $||i(x)||=||x||$ for every $x\in X$ where $i$ is the isometry between $X$ and $\hat{X}$?

Comment: I'm trying to show that the completion of a normed space is a Banach space, read: complete and normed. By definition, the completion is complete, yes. And now I am to show that the completion is normed as well - with respect to $||i(x)||_{\hat X} := ||x||_X$

Comment: It would be good if you defined where you're starting from... A general metric space doesn't have a single completion (it can have a bunch, all of which are isometric to each other). The standard completion theorems I've seen establish that the existence of completions that are metric spaces--not necessarily a space with more structure (for example, a vector space). Here you seem to be assuming (or have already proven) that $\hat{X}$ is a vector space.

Comment: Anyway, if I remember correctly, you can find a proof that for any normed space you can find a completion that is also a normed space in the book by [Kreyszig](http://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Functional-Analysis-With-Applications/dp/0471507318/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top/190-0321912-3909769).

Comment: I looked that Kreyszig-proof up, and I finally got it right. Thanks!